# java development setting path in linux

Tags: java, linux, web-services, file, path

i have development a simple webservices to upload a image to computer in linux. it have some problem the saving file location. when i summit the image, it become no response And i already import all require package.

```
@Path("/files")
public class V1_status {



/**
 * Upload a File
 */

@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public String uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail){


    saveToDisk(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail);

    return"File uploaded successfully!";

}

// save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
private void saveToDisk(InputStream uploadedInputStream,FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail
        ) {

    String uploadedFileLocation= "/home/fairlady/Pictures" +fileDetail.getFileName();


    try {
        OutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));

        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        out= new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            out.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `it havesome problem the saving file location.` yet you haven't told us what that is.

Comment: In addition to any other comments or answers, this code is terribly unsafe from a security perspective. This is pretty much the textbook definition of a path traversal attack. For your own sake, do not deploy this code anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
String uploadedFileLocation= "/home/fairlady/Pictures" +fileDetail.getFileName();
```

you are missing a forward slash after **Pictures**

try

```
String uploadedFileLocation= "/home/fairlady/Pictures/"+fileDetail.getFileName();
```